# Is it possible to setup DNS forwarding using Bind9 that translates DNS suffix?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-network, bind9

Is it possible to setup Bind9 to forward DNS requests, such that the requested DNS suffix is an alias to another longer, more complex, suffix.

For example, can I setup Bind9 to resolve DNS requests for `machine-name.my-app.internal` where these requests would be forwarded to `machine-name.k8zb98713j4bka.dx.internal.cloudapp.net`. In this scenario `my-app.internal` is suffix that would need to be translated to `k8zb98713j4bka.dx.internal.cloudapp.net`.

I have Virtual Network setup in Azure with registered custom DNS server. I setup the DNS Server using Ubuntu and Bind9 based on articles:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/301-dns-forwarder/

The Custom DNS setup works good. One issue I have come across is, if I want to communicate between VMs, using the machine name, I cannot resolve machine name only. I need to use:

```sh
ping machine-name.<unique-id>.dx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

This is annoying, and error prone, since I need to copy-paste the full suffix.

Here is named.conf.options:

```
acl goodclients {
        10.0.0.0/8;
        localhost;
        localnets;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;
        allow-query { goodclients; };

        forwarders {
                168.63.129.16;
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
        forward only;

        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

I hope to register, with custom bind9 DNS server, a 'suffix alias' if such a thing exists.

Worst case, I need to create zone file, and manually register A records to reference private IP Addresses. But I would prefer using:

```
nslookup machine-name.my-app.internal
```

instead of:

```
nslookup machine-name.k8zb98713j4bka.dx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

where both of above requests, would resolve same private IP Address without manually registering DNS A records.

Comment: Why not just use `machine-name` and configure your local resolver or `/etc/resolv.conf` to just append the base domain `k8zb98713j4bka.dx.internal.cloudapp.net`? Seems far simpler. Otherwise also look at bind RPZ features.

Answer (score 1):

> The Custom DNS setup works good. One issue I have come across is, if I
>   want to communicate between VMs, using the machine name, I cannot
>   resolve machine name only.

As far as I know, If name resolution works between VMs located in the **same virtual network**, or Azure Cloud Services role instances in the same cloud service. You could directly use **Hostname** or FQDN. Other scenarios will work with only FQDN. Check the [name resolution scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server) in Azure VNet.

So if you just work in the same virtual network, you should `nslookup` the machine name using Azure DNS Private Zones or Azure-provided name resolution. Name resolution between VMs in different virtual networks only works with FQDN.